# Question about defining a set by a recursive formula

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, definition

This is probably a trivial question, but I was a bit confused so I thought I would ask. Suppose for example take Fibonacci sequence defined by 
$F_0= 1$, $F_1 = 1$, and 
$$
F_k = F_{k-1} + F_{k-2} \ (k \geq 2).
$$

Does it then makes sense to define a set $S$ of these numbers?
Say $S = \{ F_k : k \geq 0 \}$.

I am just confused (about probably nothing to be confused about...) because the set is defined recursively which goes on forever, but we can not go to infinity... Does this always make sense or do I need some sort of axiom for this to make sense?

Could someone possibly clarify this for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential fact needed here is that a recursive definition like that of $F_n$ can be replaced by an equivalent explicit definition.  Specifically, the Fibonacci sequence $W=\{\langle k,F_k\rangle:k\in\mathbb N\}$ can be defined as the set of all those ordered pairs $\langle k,x\rangle$ such that there exists a function $f$ with the following properties: (1) the domain of $f$ is $\{0,1,\dots,k\}$ (known in set theory as $k+1$), (2) $f(0)=1$, (3) if $k\geq1$ then $f(1)=1$, (4) for all $j$ such that $2\leq j\leq k$, $f(j)=f(j-1)+f(j-2)$, and (5) $f(k)=x$.  In view of this explicit definition, we can prove the existence of $W$ by applying the separation axiom (also called subset axiom, Aussonderung, and comprehension axiom) of ZF to the set $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$.  And once we have $W$, we get the desired $S$ as the range of $W$, i.e., as the set of second components of the ordered pairs in $W$.

Comment: The possibility of converting recursive definitions to explicit ones was, as far as I know, first pointed out by Dedekind.  If it were not for this possibility, the axioms of set theory would need to include something to ensure the existence of recursively defined sets and functions.  Recursive definitions are ubiquitous in mathematics, and an axiom system that didn't provide for them would be inadequate as a foundation for mathematics.

Comment: I guess $S$ is the set of second components of ordered pairs in $W$?

Comment: @JohnnyT. Thanks. It seems I have difficulty counting as high as 2.  I'll edit the answer to incorporate your correction.

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense.

Define $S_n = \{ F_0, F_1, F_2, \dots, F_n \}$. (I think you'll agree that this set exists for every $n$.)

Then let $$S = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S_n$$

Since each $S_n$ exists, and $\mathbb{N}$ certainly exists, the union does as well (we have an axiom, the Axiom of Unions, to tell us that).

Comment: To apply the axiom of union, you need to already know not only that each of the sets $S_n$ exists but also that the infinite collection $C=\{S_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ exists, since this is the collection that you take the union of.  It seems to me that establishing the existence of $C$ is no easier than the original problem of establishing the existence of $S$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Does this not follow instantly by replacement? (I'm a bit rusty, so I apologise if I've misunderstood something.)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "we can not go to infinity".  We certainly **can** define an infinite set that way.

Comment: @user247327 I think you intended this to be a comment on the OP, not here.

Comment: In order to apply replacement, you need a set-theoretic formula defining the correspondence between $n$ and $S_n$.  That doesn't seem any easier than defining the correspondence between $n$ and $F_n$ and then using replacement to get $S$ directly.